# this.$route.params is empty in app.vue when building site global navigation (outside of router-view)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have vue setup and working fine, I can route to pages, and they are shown correctly in the router-view component. I can access this.$route.params.xyz in the components within the page, however, when trying to access in a component, such as the global navigation, the params collection is empty.

The current route URL is localhost:5011/forum/2/details where the 2 is an id value. I can access the 2 happily on the page for some local routing, but I wanted a settings page, to be available on the global menu.

```
{
  title: 'Forum Settings ',
  icon: 'mdi-cogs',
  text: 'Forum Settings ' + this.$route.params.id,
  route: {
    name: 'ForumSettings',
    params: {
      id: this.$route.params.id
    },
  },
},
```

However, params is {} and id is undefined.

How can I make this work?

route.js:

```
{
    path: '/forum/:id/settings',
    name: 'ForumSettings',
    component: ForumSettings,
    meta: {
        authorize: true,
    },
},
```

on the page itself as a test:

```
<dr-btn
    text="Settings"
    :to="{ name: 'ForumSettings', params: {id: this.$route.params.id}}"
>
    <v-icon>mdi-cog</v-icon>
</dr-btn>
```

This works fine.

in the app.vue:

```
mounted() {
    console.info('Mounted Router', this.$route);
},
```

[image: Chrome console output of this.$route]

This is not the current URL, so it seems the router isn't setup at this point. How can it be achieved to get the forum id for the current route (if it is on another page, the settings link will be hidden, so if actually no id, then no menu item)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a vuex store. Have the page that needs settings pass the id param to a vuex variable, have the navigation use a computed property that reads that vuex variable. If you have a lot more than this to do you might also consider a library that synchronizes vue router with vuex.

Comment: So, the router isn't setup at this point? I was thinking that the main menu, probably should be driven by the state of the app, rather than dynamic routes

Comment: Aren't all of your routes handled by vue router, with the main nav being the only thing outside the router-view?

Comment: yes, so if there is an ID of 5 say, which is the route, in the URL, i cannot pick it up from a component outside of the view-router component. the Main nav as it is part of the site structure is outside of the view-router component. It is showing the right stuff in the view-router component, just the params seems to be empty when accessing it from the main nav.

Comment: I just set up a test scenario for myself and console.log(this.$route) works for me in the main app mounted hook. It stops working if I remove Vue.use(VueRouter) have you maybe missed telling vue to use your imported vue router constant?

Comment: Sorry, forget that last comment, nothing works if Vue hasn't been told to use Vue Router. I don't know why you're not seeing the params in your mounted hook.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by moving my logic to navigation guards (https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)

For example:

```
const routes = [
{
path: '/',
name: 'Home',
beforeEnter:async() => {
  let loggedIn = await store.checkIfLoggedIn()
  if (loggedIn) router.push({name:'Dashboard'})
  return true
},
component: () => import('../views/Home.vue')
},
{
path: '/dashboard',
name: 'Dashboard',
beforeEnter:async() => {
  let loggedIn = await store.checkIfLoggedIn()
  if (!loggedIn) {
    router.push({name:'Home'})
  }
  return true
}]
```